# C# - EF Core dúvidas para criar modelo relacional

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

Estou iniciando em Asp Net Core e tenho a seguinte dúvida:

Possuo um modelo `Curso` e um modelo `Unidade`, um curso possui várias unidades e aquela unidade pode pertencer a mais de um curso.

Eu fiz o modelo individual de Curso e Unidade, porém, o meu problema está sendo na hora de criar o modelo de relacionamento, estava pensando em alguma forma que ele recebesse uma lista de cursos e uma unidade, porem sem sucesso.

Abaixo tenho exemplos de código do meu projeto, ao executar estou me deparando com o erro `Identity_Insert`.

```
Modelo de curso
public class Curso
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    [Required]
    [Key]        
    public long curId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(80)]
    public string curDescricao { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(1)]
    public string curStatus { get; set; }

    [StringLength(20)]
    public string curCodExterno { get; set; }

    [StringLength(60)]
    public string curObservacao { get; set; }
}

Modelo de unidade
public class Unidade
{        
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    [Required]
    [Key]
    public long uniId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [StringLength(80)]        
    public string uniDescricao { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [StringLength(1)]
    public string uniStatus { get; set; }
    [StringLength(20)]
    public string uniCodExterno { get; set; }
    public byte[] uniImagem { get; set; }
}

Modelo de CursoUnidade
public class CursoUnidade
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    [Required]
    [Key]
    public long cuuId { get; set; }

    /*[Required]        
    public long cuuCurId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("cuuCurId")]*/        
    public List<Curso> Curso { get; set; }

    /*[Required]
    public long cuuUniId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("cuuUniId")]        */
    public Unidade Unidade { get; set; }
}

Serviço de unidade
public void AddTeste(CursoUnidade cursoUnidade)
{
    _contexto.Add(cursoUnidade);
    _contexto.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: Essa é uma relação 1 pra muitos, ou seja 1 unidade pode ter vários cursos. Sendo assim você pode ter na classe unidade uma lista de cursos: `List<Curso> Cursos` .
Depois você pode adicionar os cursos na Unidade através do método List<t>.Add()

Answer (score 1):

Provavelmente em algum lugar você deve estar setando explicitamente o valor de alguma coluna de chave primária. Como você definiu as suas chaves primárias como identity, elas serão incrementadas automaticamente, e vai lançar uma exceção caso você tente definir o valor de alguma chave com essa restrição.

[Aqui](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/ef/core/saving/explicit-values-generated-properties) diz que

> para inserir valores explícitos em uma coluna IDENTITY do SQL Server, é necessário habilitar IDENTITY_INSERT manualmente antes de chamar SaveChanges();